# Consider A Busy Beaver like Turing Machine on a Mobius Strip. Is it equivalent to standard BB number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematical-analysis

I have modified Busy Beaver Turing Machine scenario. Is this new scenario equivalent to the standard one?

Consider a double sided tape twisted it into a mobius strip having P slots in total.

Initially all zeros on the slots.

Consider two adjacent slots.

We define a Mobius Busy Beaver number which is the sum total of right to left and left to right crossings on the adjacent slots by the Turing Machine.

Are these equivalent scenarios?

Question after watching [this excellent video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmAc1nDizu0)

Answer (score 2):

No. A finitely-sized tape means the Turing machine is not Turing-complete, but in fact a (very large) state machine. This makes the busy beaver number computable in your setup, and thus necessarily different than the original busy beaver numbers.

Comment: It is not finite, due to the mobius strip structure of the tape, the TM loops around. The tape becomes mutable. So TM is mutating originally written state over and over again till it halts.

Comment: If I understand you right, you are saying this is equivalent to a another TM where first round of mutations are encoded into states of this new machine and thus it becomes predictable thereafter and hence finite?

Comment: @user238607 If the alphabet of the tape has $s$ symbols, the tape has '$P$ slots' in total (regardless of whether it loops or not), and the Turing machine has $t$ possible states, the entire combined system has $t\cdot s^P$ states. Any machine that does more steps than this without halting will *never* halt, because it has fallen into a loop by the pigeonhole argument. So we have a decidable algorithm for checking if a machine halts: run it for $t \cdot s^P + 1$ steps.